# React-Native Splash Screen Control Time

Tags: react-native, splash-screen

I want to control the time of my Splash Screen. I changed/create the next files to make the splash, and it works perfectly. But I don't want to use any library for this.

`android/app/src/main/java/com/MYAPP/SpashActivity.java` `android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml` `android/app/src/main/values/styles.xml`
`android/app/src/main/res/addedAllFoldersWithPNGLogos`
`android/app/src/main/res/drawable/splash_background`

Thanks

Comment: are you coding in native android? or react native?!

Comment: react-native, coding in ubuntu so for android

Answer (score 5):

The [react-native-splash-screen](https://github.com/crazycodeboy/react-native-splash-screen) has a pretty good implementation for this.

Once you install and link the native dependencies, you can control when you show the splash screen in your native code:

Android:

```
public class MainActivity extends ReactActivity {
   @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        SplashScreen.show(this);  // here
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }
    // ...other code
}
```

iOS:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // ...other code

    [RNSplashScreen show];  // here
    // or
    //[RNSplashScreen showSplash:@"LaunchScreen" inRootView:rootView];

    return YES;
}
```

Then in your React code, you can control when to hide the splash screen

React Component:

```
componentDidMount() {
  // do stuff while splash screen is shown
  // After having done stuff (such as async tasks) hide the splash screen
  SplashScreen.hide();
}
```

React Hooks (hide after component is loaded):

```
  React.useEffect(() => {
    SplashScreen.hide();
  }, []);
```

React Hooks (hide after a timeout):

```
const [hideSplash, setHideSplash] = React.useState(false);

React.useEffect(() => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    setHideSplash(true);
  }, 1000); // amount of time the splash is shown from the time component is rendered
}, []);

React.useEffect(() => {
  hideSplash && SplashScreen.hide();
}, [hideSplash]);

// ...
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to create activity in `android` folder. all pages and views are js files inside `index.js` and you can switch between them by packages like [React Navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/). For creating an splash, you can make a `splashScreen.js` file and call it from `index.js`. In `splashScreen.js` you can set a timer and after that time, your first page of app (Home for example) calls. This is a sample code for `splashScreen.js`:

```
export default class SplashScreen extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        setTimeout(() => {
            // go to Home page
        }, 2500)
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View style={{ backgroundColor: 'white' }}>
                <View style={{ flex: 1, paddingTop: 50 }}>
                    <Text>Splash Screen</Text>
                </View>
            </View>
        )
    }
}
```

I hope this help you.

Comment: It's the way I've solve it, but not the way I want to do it. This is not an actual splash screen, it will work like it, but it isn't. Thank you very much for your answer but is not what I'm looking for! I'll keep working on it!

Comment: exactly, this solution is excellent if you always use only a 'specific' device.
the original splash screen, as @FernandoPalma had done, automatically manages all the dimensions according to the device used.
Great idea, however, that I take a lot of work ;-)

Answer (score -1):

For Android, I did like this,

Rendering all content after 2 seconds, Until 2 seconds my splash screen had appeared

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'

import Navigator from './Navigators/Main'

const App = () => {

  const [isLoad, setIsLoad] = useState(false);

  setTimeout(() => {
    setIsLoad(true);
  }, 2000);

  return isLoad ? <Navigator /> : null
}

export default App
```