# Is there a way to show splash screen on **command in** react-native?

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

I was working with react-native and I had a need to show splash screen/ or a loading screen when I log-in my user. How can I use the default splash screen? or do I have to implement one using state variables?

dependencies: latest version of every modules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually make a custom splash screen with a timer of 2 seconds. Then it navigates to the first screen. Find more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50799479/react-native-splash-screen-control-time)
.

Answer (score 3):

The package `react-native-splash-screen` includes methods to programmatically show/hide the splash screen. See the API [here](https://github.com/crazycodeboy/react-native-splash-screen#api)

Answer (score 1):

Here is an awesome package that will show/hide splash based on demand
https://github.com/zoontek/react-native-bootsplash